# Перевод дробного числа в дополнительный и обратный коды

Tags: системы-счисления

Возможно ли перевести дробное двоичное число в обратный и дополнительный коды?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В формате IEE 754 для записи мантиссы (вкупе со знаком) используется прямой код, для записи экспоненты  - прямой код со сдвигом.

Если вопрос касается своего представления вещественных чисел - да, возможно использовать обратный или дополнительный коды, придётся только самостоятельно реализовывать арифметические операции.